# Removing Complex Recursion in Thinkscript to Pinescript Conversion

Tags: pine-script, thinkscript

I have the following block of code from a longer Thinkscript file that I'm struggling to convert to Pinescript since, as I understand, Pinescript does not support recursion. What makes this conversion challenging in my view is the interdependence between the variables `state`, `trail`, and `mclose`. Does anyone have suggestions on how to cast this into Pinescript?

```
def state = {default init, long, short};
def trail;
def mclose;
switch (state[1]) {
case init:
   if (!IsNaN(loss)) {
      switch (firstTrade) { 
      case long:
         state = state.long; 
         mclose = close; 
         trail = close - loss;
      case short:
         state = state.short; 
         mclose = close; 
         trail = close + loss;
   }
} else {
   state = state.init;
   trail = Double.NaN; 
   mclose = Double.NaN;
}
case long:
   if (close > trail[1]) {
      state = state.long;
      mclose = Max(mclose[1], close); 
      trail = Max (trail[1], mclose - loss);
   } else {
      state = state.short; 
      mclose = close;
      trail = mclose + loss; 
   }
case short:
   if (close < trail[1]) {
      state = state.short;
      mclose = Min(mclose[1], close); 
      trail = Min(trail[1], mclose + loss);
   } else {
      state = state.long; 
      mclose = close; 
      trail = mclose - loss;
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out in the end that not much was required to get it to work in Pinescript. No need for iteration via a for loop. The `:=` operator is key.

```
string state  = "init"
float  mclose = na
float  trail  = na

if state[1] == "init"
    if not na(loss)
        if first_trade == "long"
            state  := "long"
            mclose := close
            trail  := close - loss
        else // first_trade = "short"
            state  := "short"
            mclose := close
            trail  := close + loss
    else
        state  := "init"
        trail  := na
        mclose := na
else if state[1] == "long"
    if close > trail[1]
        state  := "long"
        mclose := math.max(mclose[1],close)
        trail  := math.max(trail[1],mclose-loss)
    else
        state  := "short"
        mclose := close
        trail  := mclose + loss
else if state[1] == "short"
    if close < trail[1]
        state  := "short"
        mclose := math.min(mclose[1],close)
        trail  := math.min(trail[1],mclose+loss)
    else
        state  := "long"
        mclose := close
        trail  := mclose - loss
```